# why console value is 3 , I didn't Understand Closures

Tags: javascript

I understand closures but I don't understand how this example works:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        setTimeout( function timer(){
            console.log( i );
        }, i*1000 );
    }
```

In this example it logs 6 six times with a value of six. I understand this is due to closures. However, I don't understand how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: the value of `i` is 6 by the time `console.log` has fired

Comment: Don't forget that JS does not have block scopes, and all six closures you created close over the same `i` variable